# how to access original url in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httprequest

We need to do SEO redirect for urls like:

**//////controller/action**

to

**/controller/action**

Request.Url and Request.RawUrl doesn't have '////' part, it shows only one slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"].

If you are using IIS7 or above you may want to look at using the IIS Rewrite Module, which will allow you write a regex to catch URLs with multiple forward slashes and redirect them. This will save you having to write code to do it.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/